# Add a Disclaimer to Gmail App (Mail) for every user account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

What I want is, every mail that is sent out of a Google Apps account must have a disclaimer at the bottom of the mail. And I want this disclaimer to be added to every user account.

How can I accomplish this?

Note: I plan to use Outlook as the mail client.

Answer (score 4):

To add an email disclaimer to all email sent from your domain follow these steps:

1. Enable the Google Message Security service for your domain as described [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=77049).
2. Set Postini as your outbound mail gateway as described in step one [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=60730#E). When you enable the Postini service you'll be provided with the outbound mail gateway details.
3. Configure a compliance footer in the Postini console and apply it to your users as described [here](http://www.postini.com/webdocs/admin_ee_cu/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=EEHelp&file=ob_foot.html).

Source: **[Email disclaimer or compliance footer](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176538)** on the Google Apps Support Site.

Answer (score 0):

[Email Footers](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=16542%2012926930421281898119&pli=1) by [mxHero](http://www.mxhero.com/) is superb and can accomplish this. It offers highly configurable footer messages for adding to all your users' emails. With an advanced `html` editor and variable content you can design attractive and effective messages to append to emails. Create one for internal emails between users in your organization while defining another for messages sent outside your domain. You can also choose preset text for editable ideas for:

- legal disclaimers,
- ecological or inspirational phrases,
- humorous jokes.

Email Footers works for every email from your Gmail domain whether sent from webmail, cell phone or desktop clients and requires no client side software installation.